# MySQL Replication in internet environment - limitation, constrains?

Tags: mysql, replication

We have a few servers deployed in different ISPs (Internet Service Provider).
There is real-time data need to be synchronized to these servers constantly, I think MySQL Replication maybe is a good candidate for this job (we use MySQL in servers).
I know Replication works in intranet, but I'm not sure whether it works in complicated network topology in internet and in ISP subnet.
Some facts:

- Need to run as Master-Slaves, Master is to get data, about ten slave DB.
- Don't care much about replication time lag, 5 mins is fine.
- There is not much data or transactions to be synchronized per hour.
- We run Java web application in each server.

Comment: mysql replication will work anywhere that the slave can reach out and contact the master. the bigger question is how much data you'll be synching, as you'll be paying for the bandwidth used by those slaves.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend replication across a WAN due to indeterminacy of latency and availability.  There will also be issues if the remote sites have been using the same keyspace.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine. You usually want to either run it over a VPN or use SSL in the MySQL connection if it's going over the public internet.

If your write updates take more bandwidth than you have available that will of course be a limitation as the replication log will have basically every byte used in insert, update and replace statements.